# Utility to send a command to multiple terminals?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, console

A while ago when I did a lot more system admining, there was a little utility that would send a command to multiple terminals that I had open.  So essentially I could ssh into three different servers, then type `tail -f /var/log/some_error.log` into the utility and it would pass that command onto all three terminals I had open.

So essentially I typed the command once, and it was run on all three servers.  Plus the terminals were fully accessible to me so if I wanted to run commands just on that one server, I would just use the terminal ssh'ed into that one server.

After a ton of searching online, I've yet to find this utility (it was simply available on the machines we had and I can't recall the name of this particular utility).  So does anyone know of any utilities that do this?

Thanks

Comment: My first thought when reading the question was, "Don't they call that a BotNet?" LOL... sorry... couldn't resist!!!

Comment: You might want to check this related [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268128/multiple-linux-terminals-send-commands-to-all-windows-at-the-same-time

Comment: FWIW: I now use tmux and 'synchronize-panes' for doing this. https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are searching for [clusterssh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/). Love it!

Comment: Brilliant, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The little utility is called ClusTerm.